# How to convert values of strings rows of columns with multiple dots for floating points

Tags: python, pandas, data-wrangling

I am reading data; assuming it will get rid of the bad data

```
try:
  # Import CSV with error_bad_lines set to skip bad records
  data = pd.read_csv("/data.csv",  error_bad_lines=False, sep = ';')
 
except pd.io.common.CParserError:
    print("Your data contained rows that could not be parsed.")
     
data.head()
```

The column is stored as tring which I tried to conver to float

```
def make_float(num):
    num = num.replace(' ','').replace(',','.').replace("−", "-")
    return float(num)

data['total_time']  = data['total_time'].apply(make_float)


    ValueError: could not convert string to float: '-19.833.333.333.333.300'
```

However, I have some where I see values as below;

```
df 
 total_time
 '9.198.333.333.333.330'
 '5.016.666.666.666.660'
'-19.833.333.333.333.300'
  .....
  ....
```

Can someone suggest/guide how can I deal with issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should remove the commas, not change them to `.`

Comment: `thousands=','` as an argument in `pd.read_csv` should work to parse those as numeric when importing the data

Comment: @ALollz i,m afriad tried it not working.